# VBA output dialog/window or similar in Excel (2010)

Tags: excel, vba

I've little experience with VBA and Office applications.

My goal is to export data from an Excel sheet to another application. But before the export happens, I want a popup dialog or similar to appear when the user presses the "Export"-button, so he/she can review the data which will be ecxported. The reason for this is that the exported data is from various places in the sheet (or sheets), so a visual review is a good idea.

MsgBox is, of course, to small. And it's not meant for presenting lots of data.

What's a practical/elegant/effective/easy way of doing this? Ideally the popup window with the preview shoul have a "Go ahead"-button too, but this is not strictly necessary.

Comment: What you're looking for is a `UserForm`. You add it to the VBA project by right clicking on the tree on the left side and inserting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to open Visual Basic editor. On menu, choose "Insert" -> "User Form". Then you can create custom user forms with text fields, labels, check boxes, buttons etc. [Here you can find basic informations](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/userform.html).

Comment: Thanks. I AM using the VBA editor, but I wasn't aware that I added the userform from there. It seems to do what I need.